# shorthand isset followed by eval

Tags: laravel, php-7

Setting up some nav links in laravel and trying to setup some inline checks based on the URL hit which will make the nav link "active" or not, but running into an issue where i can't run an `isset()` before the expression. Not sure where I am falling short!

Just FYI - `$third` is the third bit of the URL - in this case the url is only at the `$second` level so `$third` is not defined. which means I don't want the statement to run.

```
<a class="nav-link {{ $third ?? $third === 'introduction' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="xyz"
```

How do i run

```
$third === 'introduction' ? 'active' : ''
```

only when $third exists!

Thanks

Comment: could you please explain why you cant use `isset()`

Comment: so like: isset($third ?? ''$third === 'introduction' ? 'active' : '') ---- ?

Comment: blows up with: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Comment: yep why are you using isset like that

Comment: how would you set it up? I guess there is what I am missing - can't figure out how to structure it in the right way... ?

Comment: and trying to do it inline so my include file is not one gigantic if / else madness!

Comment: Could you please try this `(isset($second) && isset($third) && $third === 'introduction') ? 'active' : '' ;`

Comment: if you set it up like that you get an: Undefined variable: third

Comment: can u try now with the edited one

Comment: is $thirs is a collection ?

Comment: I think my comment also workking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this work?

```
<a class="nav-link {{ isset($third) ? ($third === 'introduction' ? 'active' : '') : '' }}" href="xyz">
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out a way that when $third IS NOT present it doesn't blow up... hmmm

Comment: WAIT - no I am sorry I think this does work - I had $third further down on the page which was catching!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="nav-link {{ (isset($second) && isset($third) && $third === 'introduction') ? 'active' : '' }}" href="Xyz">
```